# Convert pcap file to reassemled stream(json)

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, pcap, tshark

There is pcap file for [telnet-cooked.pcap](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=telnet-cooked.pcap) that I want to extract all sessions to reassemled stream

For example in this pcap

```
192.168.0.1 -> 192.168.0.2 : "login:"
192.168.0.2 -> 192.168.0.1 : "fake"
```

How can I do that with python or another tools automatically to json that present me all the stream in pcap file ? (not with wireshark)

I care only about source and dest IP and payload

I tried to use `tshark` with command:

```
tshark -r telnet-cooked.pcap -T json >output.json
```

But I get only big json file that translate each packet to json , with lot of key that I didn't want like `eth` , and this didn't do reassemled of the stream

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a number of Python libraries that can parse pcap files; a little research will turn up several examples.

Comment: @larsks I edit the post

Comment: @Streamer So for each packet, you need only IP source and destination and payload, right?